# c language something about typedef

Tags: c, typedef

```
"In effect, typedef is like #define, except that since it is interpreted by 
 the   compiler, it can cope with textual substitutions that are beyond the 
 capabilities of the preprocessor."
```

How can we understand the sentence above?
there are two usages about typedef that I can not understand：

```
1. typedef char Line[10];
2. typedef int (*p)(char*,char*)
```

In my mind typedef A B means B is a alias of A so "typedef char Line[10]" Line[10] is  alias of char !?   (*p)(char*,char*) is alias of int !? no! obviously not! anyone can explain it?

Comment: `char Line[10];` makes `Line` a variable which is an array of 10 chars. Throw in the magic word `typedef`, and instead it makes `Line` a type which is an array of 10 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One difference between a `typedef` and a macro is that a `typedef` can include declarator information in ways that a macro cannot.  For instance, suppose you have:

```
int (*p)(int, double);
```

This declares `p` to be a pointer to an `int`-valued function that takes an `int` and a `double` as arguments.

Using `typedef`, you can define a new data type that exactly matches this:

```
typedef int (*t)(int, double);
```

You can then obtain an equivalent definition for `p` with:

```
t p;
```

Note that you can still use the full declarator syntax with `t`.  For instance, you could have:

```
t q[10];
```

This would declare an array of 10 elements of type `t`.  Without the `typedef`, this would be:

```
int (*q[10])(int, double);
```

Comment: what i wonder is the syntax of typedef. for example typedef A B . so B is a alternate of we can use B instead of A am I right? but  the sentence  " typedef int (*t)(int, double);"   confuse me, here A is int and B is (*t)(int, double) ,so i can not understand. I think it should be writted as typedef  T int (*)(int, double);

Comment: Typedefs use the exact same syntax as variable declarations. Just add the `typedef` keyword and instead of declaring a variable, you declare a type.  Your argument makes no more or less sense for variable declarations than it does for typedefs, right?

Comment: It sounds like your confusion is not with typedef, but with declarators in general.  The way to understand declarators is that the syntax mimics the syntax you would use to access the variable.  So if you have `int *a[10]`, then the expression `*a[i]` should produce an `int` (with the assumption that `i` is an integer from 0 to 9).

Answer (score 0):

`typedef char Line[10];`

This defines 'Line' which can be used to create arrays of 10 chars. For example:

`Line L;`

where L is an array of 10 chars.

`typedef int (*p)(char*,char*);`

defines a function pointer for a function which returns an int, and takes in (char*, char*). This is used to make the code which uses function pointers, more readable.

Comment: what i wonder is the syntax of typedef. for example typedef A B . so B is a alternate of we can use B instead of A am I right? but  the sentence  " typedef int (*t)(int, double);"   confuse me, here A is int and B is (*t)(int, double) ,so i can not understand. I think it should be writted as typedef  T int (*)(int, double);

Comment: Think of this an another way to use typedef: 

`typedef <return_type> (*fct_ptr)(<arg1_type>, <arg2_type>,...)`